# AppTheme not found error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

> Failed to execute aapt
>   Information:BUILD FAILED in 20s
>   Information:11 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:sample-videochat-webrtc:assembleDevDebug]
    Error:resource style/AppTheme (aka com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc:style/AppTheme) not found.
    Error:resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar (aka com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar) not found.
    Error:resource style/MatchWidth (aka com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc:style/MatchWidth) not found.
    Error:resource style/WrapContent (aka com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc:style/WrapContent) not found.
    Error:resource style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar (aka com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc:style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar) not found.
    Error:resource style/AppTheme (aka com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc:style/AppTheme) not found.
    Error:failed linking references.
    Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    Error:Execution failed for task ':sample-videochat-webrtc:processDevDebugResources'.
```

How to fix this error? Thanks in advance

Comment: show your style.xml

Comment: Can you share the line where you're getting this error and style.xml file too